# Grep for single and double digit

Tags: grep

i have path name as below,

1. abc4/2012
2. abc4/2013
3. abc45/2014
4. abc45/2014

When i grep for 45 it is showing one instance of 4 and for 4 its showing all 45.
i need to grep both single digit and double digit separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
egrep '([^0-9]4[^0-9]|[^0-9]45[^0-9])'
```

Does it for me - that is, 4 surrounded by non-digits, or 45 surrounded by non-digits.

Comment: There are also named classes (at least in GNU grep) in the form of `[:class_name:]`, e.g. `[^0-9]` can be written as `[^[:digit:]]` - this can be useful when grepping in non-POSIX locales (and when grepping for something else than numbers obviously).